# Invalid argument supplied for foreach php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach

Would someone mind checking the php code below. **https://www.linuxliteos.com/test_info/download.php returns:**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/myhosthere/public_html/test_info/download.php on line 27

```
<?
ini_set('max_execution_time', '18000');
require_once('config.php');
$ftp_server = 'ftpipaddresshere';
$ftp_user_name = 'user';
$ftp_user_pass = 'password';
$conn_id = @ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21);
if(!$conn_id)
{
    echo 'Error: Some problem in Connecting to Server!';
}
else
{
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
    $login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
    if(!$login_result)
    {
        $error_msg = 'Error: Some problem in Connecting to Vendor Server! Cron Job failed on '.date('m/d/Y H:i:s');
    }
    else
    {
        $arr_files = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, './upload');

        $arr_list = array();
        if(count($arr_files))
        {
            foreach($arr_files as $str_file)
            {
                preg_match('|-rw-r--r--   1 hwdb     hwdb.+ (\d+) ([a-zA-Z]{3} .+\d+ \d+\:\d+) (.*)|', trim($str_file), $arr_details);
                $arr_list[] = $arr_details[3];
            }
        }
        $arr_final_list = array();
        foreach($arr_list as $file_name)
        {
            if (@ftp_get($conn_id, '/home/myhost/public_html/test_info/upload/'.$file_name, 'upload/'.$file_name, FTP_BINARY)) {
                $arr_final_list[] = $file_name;
                //chmod('upload/'.$file_name, 0666);
                echo "processed";
                //Now do ftp delete
                ftp_rename($conn_id, 'upload/'.$file_name, 'processed/'.$file_name);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "error";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?
$host="localhost";
$user="dbuser";
$password="password";
$database="db";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);

?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `var_dump` to check what type your variables actually are and what they contain at that point.

Comment: replace `$arr_files = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, './upload');` to `$arr_files = array();   $arr_files = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, './upload');`

Answer (score 1):

The function [`ftp_rawlist`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) can return `false`:

> Returns an array where each element corresponds to one line of text. Returns `FALSE` when passed directory is invalid.

So that would make `$arr_files` false. The funny thing with PHP, is that it returns 1 for `count(false)`.

So you would then need to test for this condition:

```
 if ($arr_files !== false)
```

It is not necessary to check the count, as the `foreach` loop will anyway not iterate then.